# How can I split this list of strings to list of lists of ints?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of strings, it's like:

```
['25 32 49 50 61 72 78 41\n',
 '41 51 69 72 33 81 24 66\n']
```

I want to convert this list of strings, to a list of lists of ints. So my list would be:

```
[[25, 32, 49, 50, 61, 72, 78, 41], [41, 51, 69, 72, 33, 81, 24, 66]]
```

I've been thinking over this for a while, and couldn't find a solution.
By the way, the list of strings, which I gave above, is populated using

```
open("file", "r").readlines()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `split()` to split the string into list, and then use `int()` to convert them into integers.

using `map()`:

```
In [10]: lis=['25 32 49 50 61 72 78 41\n',
   ....:  '41 51 69 72 33 81 24 66\n']

In [11]: [map(int,x.split()) for x in lis]
Out[11]: [[25, 32, 49, 50, 61, 72, 78, 41], [41, 51, 69, 72, 33, 81, 24, 66]]
```

or using list comprehension:

```
In [14]: [[int(y) for y in x.split()] for x in lis]
Out[14]: [[25, 32, 49, 50, 61, 72, 78, 41], [41, 51, 69, 72, 33, 81, 24, 66]]
```

you can directly create this list from your file also, no need of `readlines()`:

```
with open("file") as f:
    lis=[map(int,line.split()) for line in f]
    print lis
...
[[25, 32, 49, 50, 61, 72, 78, 41], [41, 51, 69, 72, 33, 81, 24, 66]]
```

Comment: Thank you! A follow-up question: Is map() some sort of a type conversion in Python?

Comment: @TheConjuring `map()` applies the function passed to it to every item of the iterable, and return a list in python 2.x (it returns map object in python 3.x)

Comment: So we are basically calling the int() function to every x.split()? It is pretty clear to me now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = ['25 32 49 50 61 72 78 41\n', '41 51 69 72 33 81 24 66\n']    
map(lambda elem:map(int, elem.split()), x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  b=[[int(x) for x in i.split()] for i in open("file", "r").readlines()]
```

Try this list comprehension